# Nested test-path for multiple paths on multiple servers .... and properly outputting powershell results

Tags: powershell

My very rudimentary script does not out put the results of the query to a file.

I've tried Out-File, Export-CSV. Sometimes a file is written, but it doesn't contain any data. Its just blank.

And I believe write-host is something I should not be using, but am not skilled enough to know how i SHOULD be dealing with powershell results.

```
# Read input file of computer names and paths
$computers = Get-Content C:\temp\test-path-test.txt
$paths = Get-Content C:\temp\test-path-test-paths.txt

# Nested Loop through each computer name in the array, and each path
foreach ($computer in $computers) {

    foreach ($path in $paths) {

    $exists = Test-Path "\\$computer\$path"

    If ($exists -eq $true ) { Write-Host  $computer, $path, 'This Path Exists'}

    Else { Write-Host $computer, $path 'Path Not Found' } 
    }
}
```

I was hoping it would output a csv file of ComputerName,Path, and whether the path exists or not.

Can anyone shed any light on how I can better output the results of this to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [PSCustomObject] and gather output from the nested foreach in a variable

```
$computers = Get-Content C:\temp\test-path-test.txt
$paths = Get-Content C:\temp\test-path-test-paths.txt

# Nested Loop through each computer name in the array, and each path
$Data = foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    foreach ($path in $paths) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Computer = $Computer
            Path     = $Path
            Exists   = Test-Path "\\$computer\$path"
        }
    }
}
$Data
$Data | Export-Csv -Path New.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a custom object, add it to a list of results. Export the results however you want.

Something like this should work for you:

```
$results = @()

foreach ($computer in $computers){
    foreach ($path in $paths){

        $exists = Test-Path "\\$computer\$path"

        $results.Add(New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property (@{Computer=$computer; Path=$path; Exists=$exists}))

    }
}

$results | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "C:\Path\To\Export.csv"
```

Leave a comment if you have any issues :-)

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Wilmo Please mark one of the responses as an answer to your question and upvote it for future visitors :-)